# Hexaglide Game - Combinatorics Problem

Tags: combinatorics

Imagine a $3\times3$ board with counters in the bottom row. The only moves that can be played on this board are forwards and backwards moves; diagonal and horizontal moves are excluded and the pieces cannot be removed from the board.

[image]

In how many different ways can we move the counters from positions $A1\; A2\; A3$ to $C1\; C2\; C3$ in only $6$ moves?

My initial thought was that there are $6!$ ways of moves that can occur but then half of these moves would start from $B1\; B2\; B3$ and so there would be $\frac {6!}2$ moves but I do not know where to go from here.

I have also thought about the ways that we can move the counters, so 
$A1$ to $B1$, then $A2$ to $B2$, then $A3$ to $B3$ and so on but trying to work out all the different ways that this can be done isn't the quickest method. However my first step doing this was that there are $3!$ ways in which row $A$ all move upwards one and then $3!$ ways in which row $B$ all move up one, assuming that all three counters have moved to row $B$ by that point. This would give me $36$ ways and then I thought I would proceed via this method to work out the number of ways of moving the counters in $6$ moves

Comment: If one continuously plays forward and backward eg C1 to B1 then one will never reach A1 and number of moves will be infinity. Please can you ellaborate more on this problem

Comment: The problem takes the case that all the counters must be moved from row C to row A within 6 moves and not an infinite number of moves.

Comment: Okay so now each number will vet repeated twice so number of moves are $6!/(2!)^3$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every move is a number $1, 2$ or $3$. Every number must appear exactly twice. Hence the number of different ways to finish the game is the same as number of all possible words with characters $1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3$, which is $$\color{red}{\frac {6!}{2!\times2!\times2!}=}\color{blue}{\fbox{90}}$$.